# Salesforce end point url creation to send request to our instance

Tags: apex, webservices, rest

Please give me some idea how we can create End Point url to give another third party with access token consumer key and others.

I need to give url so that third party person will send request to me without loging into our site they need to use our service.

Answer (score 1):

Not 100 sure but It seems that Apex Rest approach will work for you. By Apex Rest you can define a custom URL path using `@RestResource` annotation on top of the class and define GET and POST methods accordingly by annotation `@HTTPGet` and `@HttpPost`.

Ex: `@RestResource(urlMapping='/Account/*')`

Here is a good reference to create Apex Rest Service with sample code https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Creating_REST_APIs_using_Apex_REST

Comment: How can we create consumer key and secrete key for authentication?